# How do I get the URL of another service in Servicestack

Tags: servicestack

I have a response type, which contains an URL to a different resource:

```
public class MyResponse
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

[Route("/bar/foo/{SerialNumber}", "GET")
public class FooRequest
{
    public string SerialNumber {get; set;}
}
```

If *MyService* returns a *MyResponse* DTO, the Location property should contain "http://mybaseurl/bar/foo/1234".
Is there some way, to create this URl in code or do I have to construct it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the docs on [Reverse Routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#reverse-routing).

You can get the relative url with:

```
var relativeUrl = new FooRequest { SerialNumber = "1234" }.ToGetUrl();
```

Or the absolute url with:

```
var absouluteUrl = new FooRequest { SerialNumber = "1234" }. ToAbsoluteUri();
```